# Adding Raster Layer without lyr file using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, raster, layers

i wonder how i can add a raster layer to a remote (not the current) mxd file with arcpy.
I need to not use a lyr file for that.

For vector Layer i have the following lines working fine :

```
mxdPath = "D:\FormationSpecialisee\IGN_IFI\doc1.mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fcADD)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer , "AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

but it seems to not work for Raster Layer.

Answer (score 11):

You can create an in-memory RasterLayer by using arcpy.MakeRasterLayer to create the layer without an .lyr file and then add it to your DataFrame.

The following code will load a raster into a new raster layer, add it to the first dataframe of the specified mxd, and then save the mxd.

```
mxdPath = r'{path to mxd}'
rasterPath = r'{path to raster file}'
rasterLayerName = 'name to give new raster layer'

md = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(md)[0]
result = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(rasterPath, rasterLayerName)
layer = result.getOutput(0)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer, 'AUTO_ARRANGE')
md.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

`mxdPath = r"D:\FormationSpecialisee\IGN_IFI\doc1.mxd"`

or

`mxdPath = "D:/FormationSpecialisee/IGN_IFI/doc1.mxd"`

or

`mxdPath = "D:\\FormationSpecialisee\\IGN_IFI\\doc1.mxd"`

For use in Python

Answer (score 3):

In a python window, just write:

```
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(rasterFileName, "tmpLyr")
```

where rasterFileName is a string containing the path and name of your raster.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to have a .lyr file pointing to a raster with your predefined symbology, then open it with `arcpy.mapping.Layer(yourlayerfile)`, add it to your map like you have, then [use one of the layer datasource update method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Updating_and_fixing_data_sources_with_arcpy_mapping/00s30000004p000000/)s to swap out the old data source with the new one.