# Adding raster from attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have a table("ecw") with a field ("raster_path") which contains the paths of many rasters (ecw type)
Selecting several rows from the table, I Would like to add the rasters into my dataframe.

How do I do it?

(Sorry if my english is not good; It isn't my native languaje)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is more arcpy based.  I would run this from the interactive window.  I left some spots in there for you to add your own information/query/etc.  I borrowed some of the raster code from [this other post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12464/arcpy-add-raster-layer-layer-without-lyr-file).

```
#get the mxd you're in
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#get the dataframe
df = mxd.activeDataFrame

#select the records via your query
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("TABLENAME", "NEW_SELECTION", "WHERE QUERY OF SORTS")

#create a cursor to go through those records
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("TABLENAME")

#go through the records
for row in rows:
    #get the path
    tablePath = row.getValue("raster_path")
    #set up the new raster layer
    rasterLayer = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(tablePath, "NAME FOR THE LAYER")
    #get the output from the in memory layer
    addLayer = rasterLayer.getOutput(0)
    #insert into the data frame
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")

del rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for your answer. I applied your code to my work.
but it doesn't works good.The first raster is added correctly,but it is no one of the  selected raster in the table.
I think the code tries to add all the files. 
And then, the code show this message:
*Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 20, in 
NameError: name 'result' is not defined*

Mi code is this:

```
#get the mxd you're in
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#get the dataframe
df = mxd.activeDataFrame

#select the records via your query
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("CATALUNA_2013", "NEW_SELECTION")

#create a cursor to go through those records
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("CATALUNA_2013")

#go through the records
for row in rows:
    #get the path
    tablePath = row.getValue("FILENAME")
    #set up the new raster layer
    rasterLayer = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(tablePath, row.NAME)
    #get the output from the in memory layer
    addLayer = result.getOutput(0)
    #insert into the data frame
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")


del rows
```

Comment: You should post these as comments instead of answers or edit your question.  I corrected my code.  The issue was I never set up the `result` variable (carry over from the other forum post).  Change it to `rasterLayer.getOutput(0)` and it should work better.  I corrected my answer above.